Looking for simple example of AMPHP with mysql 8
Hello AMPHP community,
I am new to AMPHP and am looking for a simple code example for running an asynchronous process without the main thread waiting for asynchronous feedback.
For example, imagine this use case: running a background process that logs page visit data into a database without taking up the main thread time used to display an HTML page.
Does a code example like this already exist within the AMPHP community? Could an example be shared or created?
The introductory code provided by AMPHP is very clear; however, it only includes an example of a process that communicates with the main thread via ->await();
ie.
$future1 = async(function () 
  {
    echo 'Hello ';

    // delay() is a non-blocking version of PHP's sleep() function,
    // which only pauses the current fiber instead of blocking the whole process.
    delay(2);
    echo 'the future! ';
  });

  $future2 = async(function () 
  {
    echo 'World ';

    // Let's pause for only 1 instead of 2 seconds here,
    // so our text is printed in the correct order.
    delay(1);
    echo 'from ';
  });

  // Our functions have been queued, but won't be executed until the event-loop gains control.
  echo "Let's start: ";

  // Awaiting a future outside a fiber switches to the event loop until the future is complete.
  // Once the event loop gains control, it executes our already queued functions we've passed to async()
  $future1->await();
  $future2->await();

I have explored or tried to explore several parallel environments, but appreciate the rapid and relatively hassle free environment provided by AMPHP.
